# iOS app localization, is app size increasing?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I'm currently investigating app localization, and I need to know,
if I localized 2 languages each of them have asset with size of 20MB,

is the size of the app for each appstore is 20MB, or it get the sum of it - 40MB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will be the sum.  The language of the app is not based on the app store, but the language settings on the user's device.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xcode/iOS's standard localization support, your app will contain the assets for all languages, so your app will be 40MB.

If this is too large, you can make the app download the appropriate assets the first time it is run. Many apps use this technique, and although there is an extra "downloading" stage the user experience isn't affect too much, plus the download is smaller because you only need to grab the assets for the current language. This becomes more significant when you add more languages at a later date.

Note that as of iOS 6 app *updates* can utilize delta updates (i.e. only new files are downloaded) so if the initial 40MB download isn't too much of a barrier, subsequent updates should be nice and small.